# Text Field is not displaying text entering through keyboard in Java swing. I have set the text field editable

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, mouselistener

```
void addClick(JTextField field,String s) {
    field.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //when user clicks on amount text field,
            //makes text field editable to enable user to enter amount in it
            if (field.getText().equals(s)) {
                field.setText(""); // sets the deafult text as empty string and display it
                field.setEditable(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`JTextField` is passed as parameter to `addClick` method. Initially it is not editable, i.e. `setEditable(false)`. But when user clicks on it should be made editable and user can enter the data through keyboard. `MouseListener` is working fine, i.e. it is making text field editable (sets `setEditable(true)`), but when I enter text in text field, it is not displaying the data that I am entering. By the way, I have implemented all the other methods of mouse listener interface.

Can I know how I can make text field to display data user is entering through keyboard as text field is not reading any input from the keyboard.

Comment: I have no issues - consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly - no way to decide what's wrong without a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

```
if (field.getText().equals(s))
{
    field.setText(""); // sets the deafult text as empty string and display it
    field.setEditable(true);
}
```

With this code, the program will make the JTextField editable if its content equals the String s. If the predefined/current content is not equal to s, then the JTextField won't become editable. Since you wrote only this one void method, I don't know the content, but if it is not equal to s, I assume the JTextField won't be editable.

If you want the JTextField to be editable no matter whether the current content equals s or not, then you must write `field.setEditable(true);` outside the if condition.

Comment: The field is set editable. It is not the problem. When I click on text field it is making text field editable. But the problem is when I enter data through keyboard, It is not showing in text field. I cannot figure out why

Comment: I would like to know why you want it to be not editable until you click it. The default value for isEditable is true, not false. Did you change it to false so you can change it back to true when you click on it?